# I keep running into an error within my code

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this code and when I run the code for the first time, the function works and I am able to update all the variables into a list and append that list to course_catalogue. Although, when I run my function for the second time, I get an error which says

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'availability' referenced before assignment".

Does anybody know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

This specific module of my program is aiming to add a new course with all information (courseID, Instructor name, etc. ) to a course catalogue which will end up looking like a list of lists, with each specific course being a list inside a bigger list for the course catalogue.

```
course_catalogue = []

def newcourse():
    course_code = input('What is the course code? ')
    department = input('Which department is this course in? ')
    instructor = input("What is the instructor's name? " )
    max_enrollment = input('What is the maximum enrollment for this course? ')
    current_enrollment = input('How many students are currently enrolled in this course? ')
    if max_enrollment > current_enrollment:
        availability = 'Available'
    if max_enrollment == current_enrollment:
        availability = 'Full'
    course_ID = [course_code, department, instructor, max_enrollment, current_enrollment, availability]
    course_catalogue.append(course_ID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a condition for what happens if `max_enrollment < current_enrollment` so in the event this happens availability will not exist.

Another issue is `max_enrollment` and `current_enrollment` are both strings, not integers.

```py
max_enrollment = int(input('What is the maximum enrollment for this course? '))
current_enrollment = int(input('How many students are currently enrolled in this course? '))
if max_enrollment > current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Available'
elif max_enrollment == current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Full'
elif max_enrollment < current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Overfilled' # you can use whatever term you want here, or just swap the '==' for '<=' in the previous statement
```

Comment: The last one should just be `else:`

Comment: Unless you think there's another possibility. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your if conditions are not exhaustive. In your code:

```
if max_enrollment > current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Available'
if max_enrollment == current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Full'
```

But what if the `max_enrollment < current_enrollment`

I suggest to change the part to:

```
if max_enrollment > current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Available'
elif max_enrollment == current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Full'
else:
    availability = 'Something else'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that the variable `availability` will not be there if the condition is  `if max_enrollment < current_enrollment:`

Change the condition:

```
if max_enrollment > current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Available'
if max_enrollment == current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Full'
```

as

```
if max_enrollment > current_enrollment:
    availability = 'Available'
else:
    availability = 'Full'
```